# Multiple Child domain under a single Forest

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, active-directory, nameserver

I'm new in win 2008 server so i have a question.

I have 2 Child domain under a single Forest.every thing is fine but when client in each domain want to 
log in to windows in `login on to` list user can see 2 child domain names and the forest domain name.
how can i show just its child domain name in the login list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default domain:

[DefaultDomainName Registry Key](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939708.aspx)

[Script to change Default Domain Name through GPO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555050)

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultDomainName
```

As well as the Native GPO option:

```
Computer configuration > Administrative templates > System > Logon for "Assign a default domain for logon".
```

This does not hide the other options, tough.

Comment: How can i hide Other domain names from list?

Comment: As you can see in the duplicated question, there is no easy/supported way to hide the others. You can just force a default